# My Reactjs Code Says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: reactjs

I Am Trying To Make A Programme Which Displays The Changes Made In Input Value To Output Box But Getting Error Like Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'value' of null And I Have No Idea What Is The Error Here

```js
var App =React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
        return{
            value:"My Value"
        }
    },
    updateValue:function(modifiedValue){
        this.setState({
            value:modifiedValue
        })
    },
    render:function(){
        return(
            <div className="inputBox container-fluid">
                <h1 className="text-center text-primary">Hello FreeCodeCampers !!!</h1>
                <div className="row col-md-12">
                    <InputBox value={this.state.value} updateValue={this.updateValue}/>
                    <h1>{this.state.value}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
var InputBox =React.createClass({
    update:function(){
        var modifiedValue=ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.inputValue).value;
        this.props.updateValue(modifiedValue);
    },
    render:function(){
        return(
            <input type="text" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.update} ref="initialValue"/>
        );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<App />,
document.querySelector("#app")
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="demo.js" type="text/babel"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please add some error details?

Comment: only error i get is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your version of react **(React v0.14 and above)** you don't need to call `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.inputValue)`

`this.refs.inputValue` gives you actual dom node.
You can call the methods such as `getValue()` to get the value of that node.

I hope this would solve your issue.

Comment: i tried var modifiedValue=this.refs.initialValue.getDOMNode().value; and getting error Warning: ReactDOMComponent: Do not access .getDOMNode() of a DOM node; instead, use the node directly. This DOM node was rendered by `InputBox`.

Comment: You don't need to call `getDOMNode()`. You can use `this.refs.inputValue.getValue()`

Comment: var InputBox =React.createClass({
    update:function(e){
      //  var modifiedValue=ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.initialValue).value;
      //  var modifiedValue=this.refs.initialValue.value;
        var modifiedValue= e.target.value
        this.props.updateValue(modifiedValue);
    }, so i have three method one i wrote in here which one should i practicse

Comment: yes this this.refs.inputValue.getValue() and update:function(e) also

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is coming from `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.inputValue).value;`. Your ref is `initialValue`, so the correct code should be

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.initialValue).value;
```

Further more, starting from React 0.14 I think, you can drop the findDOMNode method for reading the value and use

```
this.refs.initialValue.value
```

PS: maybe you can rename that ref to avoid the repetitive naming.

Comment: chenged input value to initialValue and it worked However when i did like var modifiedValue=this.refs.initialValue.getDOMNode().value; and got error Warning: ReactDOMComponent: Do not access .getDOMNode() of a DOM node; instead, use the node directly. This DOM node was rendered by `InputBox`.